# GCE instance ignoring service account roles

Tags: google-cloud-platform, service-accounts, google-iam

I am currently trying to provision a GCE instance that will execute a Docker container in order to retrieve some information from the web and push them to BigQuery.

Now, the newly created service account (screenshot below) doesn't affect the api scopes whatsoever. This obviously makes the container fail when authenthicating to BQ. Funny thing is, when I use the GCE default service account and select auth scopes manually from the GUI everything works like a charm.

I am failing to understand why the following service account doesn't open api auth scopes to the machine. I might be overlooking something really  simple on this one.

[image]

#### Context

The virtual machine is created and run with the following `gcloud` command:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
gcloud compute instances create-with-container gcp-scrape \
    --machine-type="e2-micro" \
    --boot-disk-size=10 \
    --container-image="gcr.io/my_project/gcp_scrape:latest" \
    --container-restart-policy="on-failure" \
    --zone="us-west1-a" \
    --service-account gcp-scrape@my_project.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --preemptible
```

This is how bigquery errors out when using my custom service account:

```
Access Denied: BigQuery BigQuery: Missing required OAuth scope. Need BigQuery or Cloud Platform read scope.
```

Comment: Please include more details as to how you're running the VM as the service account and what errors you're receiving. (OAuth) scopes and IAM (permissions) do interact and I assume you've given the VM the broad `cloud-platform` scope. Since the only change is the service account, the only difference is between the default service account and the one you've created.

Comment: Hi @DazWilkin, as mentioned I've added a bit more context on how I create the instance and the bq error that pops up in the container.

Comment: Also, it seems that the default compute engine account has `Editor` access on all resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified a `--scopes` flag, so the instance uses the [default scope](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#:%7E:text=com/auth/datastore-,default,-https%3A//www.googleapis) which doesn't include BigQuery.

[To let the instance access all services that the service account can access](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes), add `--scopes https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` to your command line.

Comment: And today I've learned that roles and scopes are two different things